# How to use scopus API to get the names of all the authors for a given article?

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, scopus

I have a dataset of publication titles and I want to find the corresponding author names for the same, how do I use Rstudio to retrieve the same? I have already retrieved the API key and am using the following code:

```r
get_author_names <- function(title) {
  query <- paste0('TITLE-ABS-KEY("', title, '")')
  
  cat("API Query:", query, "\n")
  
  result <- scopus_search(query = query, count = 1)
  
  print(result)  

  if (!is.null(result$entries) && length(result$entries) > 0) {
    # Extract author names
    authors <- result$entries[[1]]$`dc:creator`
    
    if (!is.null(authors)) {
      cat("Authors:", paste(authors, collapse = ", "), "\n")
      return(authors)
    } else {
      cat("No authors found\n")
      return(NULL)
    }
  } else {
    cat("No authors found\n")
    return(NULL)
  }
}
```

When I use the above, however, the `dc:creator` field only comprises of the first author name, even when the article has multiple authors. How do I retrieve names of all the authors?